# AJAX not sending data / possible incorrect syntax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't get my form data to be sent. My scenario:
Page 'user.php' holds a form. The text field within should send the data to up_cap.php, then send it back to user.php and be displayed in  without a page refresh.

So basically: user types info in a text field, then on submit it appears in the  next to it without page refresh. The data isn't being received by the .php page.

I believe my problem is the syntax turning the form data into AJAX info, or the AJAX into the PHP.
I've been working on this for two days! Any help/thoughts greatly appreciated.

I based my code off:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

**HTML**(user.php)

```
 <div id="the_boxx" class="popUp2">
 <? include 'up_cap.php'?>
 </div><!--end popUp-->
```

**HTML FORM** (user.php)

```
<form name="cap_update">   
              <input id="c_a_p" name="c_a_p" value="" size="30"
              class="validate[required] input" type="text" />
              <div class="clearfix;"></div></div>
              <button id="update_info" type="submit" 
               style="float:right;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;" 
               class="chg" >Update</button>
              </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (located at bottom of user.php body)

```
<script>
$('.chg').click(function() {    
 var c_a_p = $("#c_a_p").val();
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "up_cap.php",
     data: "c_a_p",
     success: function() {  
  $('#the_boxx').load('up_cap.php')     
      }  
     }); return false;      

    });
 </script>
```

**PHP** (up_cap.php)

```
 <?
 $vaar = $_REQUEST['c_a_p'];
 echo $vaar;
 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.load('up_cap.php')` within the success callback? You have already successfully posted the request to that page

Comment: Because the input-data needs to be displayed within that <div>

Comment: Change it to `success: function(html) {  $('#the_boxx').html(html); }`  The first argument will be the result of the AJAX request. At the moment you are re-executing the request when it completes. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: this is displaying in the correct <div> but I can't echo it out when I view up_cap.php directly. If I comment out everything in up_cap.php it will not display my input. So the input must be reaching up_cap.php, but why can't I see the result of'echo $vaar when my URL is .../up_cap.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here: The answer was AlexP's suggestion. Since he didn't comment back or post as an answer, I can't give him the points. Either way, my solution indeed was my syntax just as I suspected.

```
success: function(html) { $('#the_boxx').html(html); }
```

also this was needed:

```
data: "c_a_p=" + c_a_p,
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this way :)

```
data: {key:value}
```

And in php

```
$_POST['key']
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Here is your syntax corrected. you didn't craft your `data` string appropriately.

```
$('.chg').click(function() {    
 var c_a_p = $("#c_a_p").val();
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "up_cap.php",
     data: "c_a_p=" + c_a_p,
     success: function() {  
  $('#the_boxx').load('up_cap.php')     
      }  
     }); return false;      

    });
 </script>
```

Comment: my answer uses direct `post` payload while the answer below provides a `json` input and have `jquery` convert it to the same `payload` i created. if none of the answers are working for you then you doing something wrong some where else.

Answer (score 0):

Change data to-

```
data: { cap : c_a_p } ,
```

and in Php

```
$vaar = $_REQUEST['cap'];
```

Comment: I think this is the direction I need to go, but the data still isn't reaching up_cap.php.